# replace double quotes with single php

Tags: php, html, string

I have a text type "test", and I want 'test', I have used str_replace ("" "," '") but it has not worked for me, so that the text can be seen as html in a pdf

Answer (score 2):

You have to [escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) the quotes. It won't recognize it otherwise:

```
$new = str_replace('\'', "\"", $old);
```